# How can I configure Tcl 8.5 to enable threads on Linux?

Tags: linux, multithreading, tcl, tk-toolkit

I have installed tcl 8.5 as well as tk on my linux computer, but I need to be able to use threads for a project. I'm aware that this needs to be enabled separately if you downloaded tcl/tk from a binary file, and that it has something to do with configuring using the keywords --enable-threads.

However, for the life of me I can't figure out where to do this and the exact terms I need to use. "configure" or "./configure" is not a term my linux terminal understands, and I'm probably not starting from the right directly either.

Can someone please tell me how to enable threads for tcl on a Linux machine from the beginning?

Comment: What is your exact Linux distribution? Can you freely use a package manager at your discretion?

Comment: I'm using CentOS, but my work does not allow us to use a package manager. I originally downloaded tcl/tk from some rpm files that were cleared as safe.

Comment: Which CentOS version, exactly? Are you allowed to fetch and rebuild the source rpm (srpm)? If so, you could install the srpm and rebuild using the needed extra flag?

Comment: If you have to take the clearance route anyway, why not convince work to move to Tcl 8.6 for the new project, it brings what you need for a multi-threaded project: thread-enabled default builds, bundled Thread package etc. Besides, 8.5 has reached its EOL.

Comment: The configure script is in the unix subdirectory, so you would normally do `unix/configure --enable-threads` from the top directory (tcl8.5.19). I personally like to create a subdirectory to perform the build from. In that case I'd use `../unix/configure --enable-threads` for a threaded build. But I second the advise to use Tcl 8.6 instead.

Comment: @mrcalvin I am working on CentOS 7, I believe. This is actually my first time working on a linux machine and I wasn't aware we could build rpm files with a particular flag. That might help. Tcl8.5 is what my company already had on hand and so that's what I was asked to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When building Tcl on Unix from source, *assuming you have a compiler installed,* you change to the `unix` directory in the source tree and do:

```
# First, set things up. (See below for what options to use.)
./configure ...options...

# Then, to actually do the build
make

# Possibly then you might run the test suite...
make test

# Finally, you'll install it to its working location
make install
# Might be:
#    sudo make install
# if installing to a shared location
```

The options you will probably need are:

- `--prefix=$DIR` where you replace `$DIR` with somewhere you can write to during `make install`.
- `--enable-threads` (you asked for this explicitly)

There are a few other things that can be set, but they tend to either be things that we autodetect adequately, or that are mostly only needed when developing Tcl itself (like extended debugging modes).

You might also need to say which compiler to use. Do that the standard way, by setting (and exporting) the `CC` environment variable before calling any of the above. The configure script will guess if you don't say, but it doesn't try very hard.

Comment: You can also build out-of-tree. Either way should work. The number of warnings should be extremely small. And 8.5 is basically end-of-life now.

Comment: I am on a Linux machine, not unix. As far as I know (this is my first time using a Linux machine, so I might be wrong), there's no Unix directory for me to go to. Using ./configure results in a "no such command" response when I try to use it in my terminal.

Comment: Donal's answer assumes you downloading the source tarball of 8.5, unpacking it and, therein (in the "source tree"), `cd`'ing into the "unix" subdirectory. In this subdir, you will find a shell script `configure`, then one to be executed.

Comment: Oh, that makes a lot more sense. Thank you for explaining. I installed it from an rpm file, so I'm not 100% sure about that. I will take a look.

Comment: So I did find the Unix directory. Inside it are three files: tclDTrace.h, tclUnixPort.h, and tclUnixThrd.h. (That last one is for threads, so yay progress!) I don't see a shell script called configure through. I did try cd'ing into the Unix subdirectory and attempting to do the configure command anyway, just in case, but no luck.

Comment: I found what I think is a configure file, but it's called tclConfig.sh instead of the more generic configure. For some reason I can't actually execute it though. I cd'd into the directory where the config file is and then tried "./tclConfig.sh --prefix=<directory/path/here> --enable-threads", and it didn't complain but...also nothing changed. No make file to work with at this point.